# displaying of email edit text field with buttons submit and cancel on clicking forgot password button

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am making a app where i need to display a email edit text field with 2 buttons submit and cancel when i click forgot password button and it should display below it. Could anyone please help me with the xml layout info and java as well. Help appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LoginLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounders_fpass"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="PASSWORD"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounders_email"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="EMAIL ID"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="LOGIN" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Forgot Password?" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appear"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="APPEAR" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
  public class Login extends Activity {
    Button log, fp;
    TextView forgot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);


        // views
        views();

        // clicklistener
        setClickListenerOnButton_log();
        setClickListenerOnButton_fp();
    }

    private void setClickListenerOnButton_fp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setContentView(forgot);
                forgot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void views() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        fp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fp);
        forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appear);
    }

    private void setClickListenerOnButton_log() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: show your layout file

Comment: @NoName he said want to know xml layout info and java as well as means spoon feeding ...

Comment: check [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) and try to explore yourself first.

Comment: Atleast show us what are your efforts, we will definitely help you. But asking question in this way is not acceptable.

Comment: I have uploaded my java class could anyone please look into it and tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: @A.R.Thank you very much for the reply and answer!! Its not crashing and its displaying the textview with my desired text.

Comment: Your welcome Siddhivinayak Guthi..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 Just Remove  
 "setContentView(forgot);" Line 

  from your setClickListenerOnButton_fp().
```

And run your App. Your App will not crash.

Try and let me know, is this resolves your issue.